# Sending dictionary as Django model attribute

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

Is there any possibility to send some `keyword: argument` into django model attribute (one attribute)? I tried to use `models.TextField` for that but there must be better solution.

```
from django.db import models


class Newsletter(models.Model):
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)
    filter = models.TextField()
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: A `JSONField`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I thought about it but there is another problem. Is there any possibility to encode string to JSON (because I send the value for this attribute as a string)?

Comment: `json.dumps()`? Look at the Python `json` module doc.